# add_rect identifier not found c++

Tags: c++

I am getting an error in my C++ code.

Here is part of the relevant code, it is located in pathfinding.h file. (GitHub link to full project is at the bottom):
    template 
    struct Graph{   //this will be the map
        typedef tuple Location;   //basically an (x,y) coordinate
        static array DIRS;

```
    unordered_set<Location>walls;

    int width, height;
    Graph(int width_, int height_) :width(width_), height(height_){}    //constructor

    inline bool in_bounds(Location id){ //make sure in bounds
        int x, y;
        tie(x, y) = id;
        return 0 <= x<width && 0 <= y<height;
    }

    inline bool passable(Location id){  //check if wall
        return !walls.count(id);
    }

    vector<Location> neighbors(Location id){    //return 4 neighbors
        int x, y, dx, dy;
        tie(x, y) = id;
        bool possible;
        vector<Location> results;
        for (auto dir : DIRS) {
            tie(dx, dy) = dir;
            Location next(x + dx, y + dy);
            if (in_bounds(next) && passable(next)) {
                results.push_back(next);
            }
        }
        if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
            // aesthetic improvement on square grids
            std::reverse(results.begin(), results.end());
        }
        return results;
    }
    inline void add_rect(Graph& grid, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) { //create walls (this part doesn't work atm)
        for (int x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
            for (int y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
                grid.walls.insert(Graph::Location{ x, y });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Actually it's mostly the add_rect function that is relevant and the unordered_set.

Here is the code in the main:

```
Graph<int> grid(30, 10);    //all 
    add_rect(grid, 0, 0, 1, 10);    //of 
    add_rect(grid, 1, 0, 30, 1);
    add_rect(grid, 12, 1, 13, 2);
    add_rect(grid, 16, 1, 17, 2);
    add_rect(grid, 12, 2, 13, 3);
    add_rect(grid, 16, 2, 17, 3);   //this
    add_rect(grid, 12, 3, 17, 4);   //doesn't
    add_rect(grid, 1, 9, 30, 10);   //work
    add_rect(grid, 29, 1, 30, 9);   //right
    add_rect(grid, 4, 5, 25, 6); // now
```

Here is the list of errors:

```
error C3861: 'add_rect': identifier not found (all of the lines with add_rect in the main)
error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.
```

Basically the add_rect is supposed to create walls and add them to the unordered_set named walls in the Graph class. I have included "pathfinding.h". I tried forward declaration but it just caused more errors. I don't know how to make a suitable hash function for unordered_set, any help on that?

Also, please tell me how to make my questions better, first timer here.

Github link: https://github.com/Aopser101/pacman

thanks for your time.

Comment: Move your `add_rect` outside of `Graph`

Comment: Tried that, it gives a bunch of new errors.

Comment: But are they better errors? One error could be hiding a hundred more, so fixing problem X may look like it caused even more error messages. @torvin looks to be right. Add_rect appears to be part of the Graph struct. Either make it static and prefix calls to it with Graph:: to satisfy the namespacing or remove it from the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `add_rect` method belongs to a struct, so it should operate on `this` rather then on externally passed object. It should look like this:

```
inline void add_rect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) { //create walls (this part doesn't work atm)
    for (int x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
        for (int y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
            walls.insert(Graph::Location{ x, y });
        }
    }
}
```

And should be called like this:

```
Graph<int> grid(30, 10);
grid.add_rect(0, 0, 1, 10);
grid.add_rect(1, 0, 30, 1);
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in the shown code:

```
add_rect(grid, 0, 0, 1, 10);
```

`add_rect` is a inline member function of the `Graph` class, it needs to be called with an instance of your class since it is not static. If it is static, you need  to call it with `Graph::add_rect(...)`

Meanwhile, your `Graph` class is **NOT** a class template, while you are using it as it is: `Graph<int>`.

The solution is either of the following:

1. Move `add_rect` outside of your class and define it as a utility function that is not belonging to the `Graph` class
2. Create an instance of `Graph` at first, then call it with `.` operator
3. Change `Graph<int>` to `Graph` or make a real class template

Comment: Oops, I forgot to paste the template into my question, sorry.